# uninitialized constant error after change style of children definitions at classes and modules

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a gem where all classes that include a module are like this

```rb
require 'concurrent_rails/adapters/future'

module ConcurrentRails
  class Promises
    include ConcurrentRails::Adapters::Future
```

and this is the module

```rb
module ConcurrentRails::Adapters
  module Future
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    class_methods do
      ....
```

this works fine but I'm trying to keep the definition of classes and modules in a single line:

```rb
module ConcurrentRails::Adapters::Future
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    ...
```

when I change the definition like above, without touching the `promises.rb` file, I get this error:

```
future.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ConcurrentRails::Adapters (NameError)
```

I tried `require` the file before, on the `concurrent_rails.rb` definition but nothing worked.

If it helps, [here](https://github.com/luizkowalski/concurrent_rails) is the source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, I'd advise against nested class/module definitions. Sure, it saves a line of code/indentation, but you run in to this sort of issue.

For example, see [this `rubocop` rule](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/ClassAndModuleChildren):

> Class: RuboCop::Cop::Style::ClassAndModuleChildren
>
> **Overview**
>
> This cop checks the style of children definitions at classes and
> modules. Basically there are two different styles:
>
> The compact style is only forced for classes/modules with one child.
>
> Examples:
>
> - EnforcedStyle: nested (default)
>
>   ```
>   # good
>   # have each child on its own line
>   class Foo
>     class Bar
>     end
>   end
>   ```
> - EnforcedStyle: compact
>
>   ```
>   # good
>   # combine definitions as much as possible
>   class Foo::Bar
>   end
>   ```

Defining **nested** modules is problematic, as it only works in ruby if the parent module has already been defined. For example:

```
irb(main):001:1* module Foo::Bar
irb(main):002:0> end
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
NameError (uninitialized constant Foo)
```

Whereas this works fine:

```
irb(main):001:1* module Foo
irb(main):002:2*   module Bar
irb(main):003:1*   end
irb(main):004:0> end
```

Additionally, even if the parent module has already been defined, you can still run into [other issues with module nesting in ruby](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/avoid-these-traps-when-nesting-ruby-modules/).

So, in short: `module ConcurrentRails::Adapters::Future` didn't work, because `ConcurrentRails::Adapters` hadn't been defined yet.

You **could** resolve this by explicitly defining that "parent module" first, however, I wouldn't advise 3+ layer nested module definitions regardless.

Comment: This rubocop rule is exactly what I'm trying to solve. I set `EnforcedStyle: compact` but then ran into this issue above. You said `You could resolve this by explicitly defining that "parent module" first` but I believe I didn't get what you are saying...should I drop the `adapters` sufolder? should I create a `adapters.rb` file inside `adapters` that require these files?

Comment: I don't think file or folder names are relevant to your question. The point is that `ConcurrentRails::Adapters` has not been defined, so ruby gets confused when trying to immediately define `ConcurrentRails::Adapters::SomethingNestedDeeper`.

Comment: Does `ConcurrentRails::Adapters` have any meaning on its own? What does that module contain, other than other classes? If the answer is "nothing", then does it really need to be a module in the first place? Would it make sense to just apply a naming convention like `ConcurrentRails::FutureAdapter` instead of `ConcurrentRails::Adapters::Future`?

Comment: `If the answer is "nothing", then does it really need to be a module in the first place?` that opened my mind, you are right. I dropped the submodule. Thanks a lot

Comment: `Defining nested modules is problematic` ... but then you show a compact definition. Aren't you saying that compact definitions are problematic? It seems like **compact**  definitions can only be used to append to a module, whereas **nested** definitions can be used for both creating and appending. In that light, my personal preference would be to stick to a single syntax -- **nested**.